# Opencv app compiled in ubuntu not working in redhat "symbol lookup error"

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, redhat

I have developed an application with eclipse CDT in ubuntu that uses OpenCV to get frames from a video and process it. I compiled and executed it with no problems in ubuntu but when i try to run it in redhat i have this problem:

```
./PruebasOpencv: symbol lookup error: ./PruebasOpencv: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv12VideoCaptureC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I have instaled and compiled opencv-2.4.9 in both OS with cmake
Ubuntu version 16.04
RedHat version RHEL 7.1

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Did you compile it in RedHat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile your application in RH too. I don't know if compiled application in Ubuntu is binary compatible to RH. Perhaps there are some libraries dependencies missing in RH.

You can check your application dependencies by:

```
ldd yourApp
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly, i will try it

Comment: I have compiled the code in redhat and it worked! Sometimes the easiest solution is the one we do not want to see